# Unable to click on dropdown element using for loop

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium2, javascript

I wrote a for loop code that can access a dropdown list. I'm able to print the list but the code is unable to click on the specified option

```
public void userCapturesAccountDetails()  
{
    WebDriver driver = contextSteps.getDriver();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@data-id='idSbxPractice']")).click();
    List<WebElement> dropdown = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='dropdown-menu inner selectpicker']/li/a/span"));

    for(int i = 0; i < dropdown.size(); i++)
    {
        WebElement element = dropdown.get(i);
        String innerhtml = element.getAttribute("innerHTML");

        if(innerhtml.contentEquals("OptionSelect"))
        {
            element.click();
            break;
        }
        System.out.println("values from dropdown is ======= "+innerhtml);
    }
        driver.quit();
}
```

**HTML :**

```
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" style="margin-top: 130.5px;">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close"></button>
<h4 class="modal-title">Add New Account</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<div class="row">
<div>
<div class="col-md-12">
<div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-8">...</div>
<div class="col-md-16 has-success">
<select class="bootstrap-select data-size="10" id="idSbxPractice" data-live-search="true" tabindex="1" Style="display: none;"
<option>
<span> class="text" title="SelectOption">SelectOption</span>
</option>
```

Comment: Can you add the error/exception you are getting when attempting to click the element?

Comment: What you've posted appears to be an XPath; can you please post the actual HTML for the dropdown list? It will help to determine the best way to uniquely identify your target element.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the WebDriver (Chrome vs Firefox, etc), you may find that you have to click the anchor rather than the span. Try adjusting your XPath to the following.

```
//ul[@class='dropdown-menu inner selectpicker']/li/a
```

Note that this means you may also have to adjust your option string matching logic. Rather than using `innerHtml`, you may have to access the element text, or find some other attribute that allows you to uniquely identify the desired element.

**EDIT**

The HTML you added to the question does not seem to match the code you wrote at all. For example, you are trying to locate an element of type `<button>`, and there are no buttons in the HTML. The case is similar for the list elements.

Comment: Clicking on a link instead on a span makes sense.

Comment: I adjusted the XPath to //ul[@class='dropdown-menu inner selectpicker']/li/a and it still doesn't work. The click to element is skipped and no error message is produced.

Comment: I think the HTML has no unique identifiers and it doesn't make it easy for the drive to locate elements on the dropdown. I have edited the question, please see the HTML.

Comment: @VanderLinden I have added the correct HTML

Answer (score 1):

Since the tag name is select, try using the following:

```
Select _select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#idSbxPractice")));
try {
    _select.selectByVisibleText("OptionSelect");
} catch (Exception e) {
    // in case "OptionSelect" is not present in the dropdown list.
    System.out.println("values from dropdown is ======= "+innerhtml);
}
```

This will remove the need for a ''for'' loop.

Comment: This looks likely to be the best bet based on the updated HTML. I would also note that the visible test for that option is "SelectOption", not "OptionSelect", which was included both here and in the code provided in the question.

Comment: Also, since the `<select>` element has an @id attribute, you can locate it thusly: `driver.findElement.byId("idSbxPractice")`